# Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser. The file does not match your project config: jest.config.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, eslint

I created a modularization of the paths in ts.config, however, when I added moduleNameMapper to jest.config.js it returned the error:

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: jest.config.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.
```

`.tsconfig.js`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    collectCoverageFrom: [
      '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{ts, tsx}'
    ],
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    transform: {
      '.+\\.tsx$': 'ts-jest',
      '.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '@/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exclude `jest.config.js` in the `.eslintignore` file